# Handling data fetched from an api, do I need state management?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build a Flutter application, and got a little confused about how should I handle data fetching.
I'm using Supabase, and I have a table of items. I have a `FutureBuilder widget` to fetch the data and populate a `ListView` with it.
This is my fetch function:

```
static Future<List<CustomItem>> fetchItems() async {
   List<CustomItem> items = [];
   var fetchedItems = await _client
   .from("items")
   .select('name, price, color, category')
   .execute();

   for (var item in fetchedItems.data) {
    String name = item['name'];
    double? price = toDouble(item['price']);
    String color = item['color'];
    String category = item['category'];

    CustomItem i = CustomItem(name, price!, color, category);
    items.add(i);
   }

   return items;
  }
```

I want to display a widget on top of my screen, to display the sum of the items price, how should I approach that?
As you can see, currently I have an items list in my fetchItems function, so it is not accessible to other functions.

Do I need a state management and save the items list there so I can access it and then calculate?
I tried using items list in the class instead of the function, but then it just adds the items to the list every refresh, so I get a lot of duplicates, and I'm trying to avoid having a lot of api calls.

Comment: I would suggest you to use state management here, if you are going with `providers` then simply store a List in provider and get the sum. If you are using `BloC - Cubits/states` then do the same in the `states` the job will be done

Comment: @Hamza Thank you very much! I still don't know what to use (new to Flutter) but I will do my research.

Comment: No worries at all man, I work in BloC - Cubit/State library, ping me in case you need any help!